# Eclipse RCP 4.2 - Is it suitable for Commercial Applications

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Is Eclipse RCP 4.2 JUNO stable for developing commercial applications ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E4 is good step ahead. But! If you are not forced to start with E4 now, wait at least till first SR (Service Release). E4 is stable but much slower on the same hardware then 3.x line. Moreover many famous Eclipse textbooks are not yet updated for E4.

Answer (score 0):

this is stable ,you can use Eclipse RCP 4.2 JUNO for commercial purpose